# XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Unloaded resources show caution: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy

I actually don't know the right title for this question, because of I've found many similars but still couldn't figure the solution out.

My problem is that (on Chrome) the website I've working on remain showing console log: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load **http://resource.domain.com/file.css**. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '**http://www.my-site-url.tld'** is therefore not allowed access.*

[image: error message on console log]

I've tried to allow that resources via .htaccess files using this code.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://wp.com,http://ajax.googleapis.com,http://fonts.googleapis.com,http://zor.fyre.co
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Doesn't work. I've also tried php and jsonp version.

Anyone please help me to fix this issue.

**Additional info:**
Lately, in inspect elements > Networks > Headers section, I found this message:
[image: CAUTION: Provision headers are shown]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue most likely stems from the fact that you are trying to load content from an external domain, which is prohibited in a normal json call hence the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. The technique you may need is known as JsonP. I would link the documentation; however, it really can depend on the javascript framework you are using. I recommending reviewing this post for a walk-through on how to invoke this behaviour via normal JS. https://stackapps.com/questions/891/how-to-call-the-api-via-jsonp-in-plain-old-javascript

Hope this helps!

Comment: But for css file from http://fonts.googleapis.com, which previously marked as _XMLHttpRequest cannot load_, went working after I add prefetch, like _<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet prefetch' type='text/css'>_ surprisingly some assets from external url go fine.

But this is not helping for some external css file from livefyre, http://zor.fyre.co.

I couldn't explain this clearly, just sharing this experience.