# Caution provisional headers are shown in all browsers only on local machine

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-csrf

I am developing a page. now since today in the morning, i cannot send ajax post calls, and getting this error:

```
Caution provisional headers are shown
```

even if i disable adblock and put all necessary crsf tokens in posts, i am still not able to do posts as ajax..

yesterday i was able to do all these calls, i tried now by deleting sessions and cookies in browser but nothing changes.. still having the same problem.

but in my live page, having the same code, it is working without any problems..

what should i do now?

Comment: Are you loading any resources from a different domain?

Comment: I am having this issue with a SWF file loading cross domain from Amamzon s3, where it has worked fine for YEARS, but suddenly will sporadically fail with Caution Provisional Headers in network panel for some time, and eventually a strange Content Length error in the console at which point the request in network panel changes to 200 OK (which it is definitely not ok).  

Found this in AWS docs but I don't think it's the issue, to do with redirect response:

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTRedirect.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTRedirect.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to some Chrome extension which is blocking the request. To debug, you can try incognito mode or `--disable-extensions` option from command line.

Another debug trick is shared on ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger#comment31917985_21179105):

> The way I found about the extension that was blocking my resource was through the chrome://net-internals tool in Chrome. Just type that in the address bar and hit enter. Then open the page that is showing problems. Then go back to net-internals, click on events (###) and use the textfield to find the event related to your resource (use parts of the URL). Finally, click on it and see if the info shown tells you something.

Comment: Really thanks, I spend like 3 hour trying debug my application until find this post. Adblock was messing with my admin exclude banner function (ajax) in the admin of my application. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pratyush There is a similar issue posted in this [**SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284111/php-jquery-ajax-call-throws-neterr-empty-response) but there doesn't seem to be any possible explanation for this **Provisional Headers Sent** issue. 
Any concrete solution for this? really annoying! I posted this question some time before. There is no Adblock too. I also inspected with Net-tools on Chrome, there isn't anything clear to me. Someone please help.

Comment: webblover: i am having the same problem, no extensions installed.