# Why the response details vary in case of Firefox and Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-mvc-2, css-sprites

I am working on implementation of CSS Sprite for asp.net mvc2 application. I followed the below article and tried to work on a sample project.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek1ASPNETSpriteAndImageOptimization.aspx

I have added few images to the App_Sprites folder and then run the application. Updated the Site.master and Index.aspx view of HomeController with the following code :

Site.master:

```
<%: Sprite.ImportStylesheet("~/App_Sprites/") %>
```

Index.aspx:

```
<%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/community_icon_dkgreen.jpg")%>
     <%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/community_icon_lightblue.jpg")%>
     <%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/community_icon_ltgreen.jpg")%>
     <%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/elearning_icon_dkblue(979183).gif")%>
     <%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/elearning_icon_dkgreen(552670).gif")%>
     <%: Sprite.Image("~/App_Sprites/elearning_icon_mdblue(516430).gif")%>
     <div class="community_icon_dkgreen.jpg"></div>
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to know why there is a difference in the response and request count?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Comment: A wild guess... caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! Here is my perception. Firefox is showing correctly all the server requests it made. Whereas Chrome also shows provisional header requests which does not make a real request to server. Base64 encoded image bytes have been already downloaded as part of **highCompact.css** file request. Here is an answer I can relate - [Caution provisional headers are shown in chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21179105/212661)

Comment: I checked the sample using Fiddler and found that the Fiddler request count matches with Firefox request count.Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me a lot to understand the internals.:)