# lost logout functionality for grails app using spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a grails app that moved to a new subnet with a change to the DNS. As a result, the logout functionality stopped working. When I inspect the network using chrome, I get this message under request headers: `CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.`

This means request to retrieve that resource was never made, so the headers being shown are not the real thing.

The logout function is executing this action

```
package edu.example.performanceevaluations

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class LogoutController {

    def index = {
        // Put any pre-logout code here
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl // '/j_spring_security_logout'
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate a direction to look towards.

Comment: have you tried the debugging the network events as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21179105/2543138?

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by that link run chrome://net-internals and see if you get anywhere

If you are still lost, I would suggest a two way debugging if you have Linux find something related to your traffic and run either something like `tcpdump` or if thats too complex install and run `ngrep -W byline -d any port 8080 -q`.  and look for the pattern see what is going on.

ngrep/tcpdump and look for that old ip or subnet on entire traffic see if anything is still trying get through - (this all be best on grails app server ofcourse
(unsure possibly port 8080 or any other clear text port that your app may be running on)

Look for your ip in the apache logs does it hit the actual server when you log out etc?

Has the application been restarted since subnet change since it could have cached the next point from application in the running Java process:

```
pgrep java|awk '{print "netstat -plant "$1" |grep  "$1 }'|/bin/sh
or  
pgrep java|awk '{print " lsof -p "$1" |grep -i listen"}'|/bin/sh
```

I personally think something somewhere needs to be restarted since its hooking on to a cache of something .

Also check the hosts files of any end machines involved ensure nothing has previous subnet physically configured in there.