# Strange behaviour in images uploading using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: jquery, upload, jquery-file-upload

I'am using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to upload images on server. Sometimes image uploads freeze server and in developer tools appear message "Provisional headers are shown".

Here is one of such files ([view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Rnzjn7edbSbEMtZUUzWjNHTWM/edit?usp=sharing)). It name DSCN2594.JPG. But when I change name to CN2594.JPG (delete 2 first letters) or I suppose on any another name - upload works fine.

Why it may happen? I'am already break my brain!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552146/caution-provisional-header-are-shown, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger might mean something, or not. Both of the links try to resolve the issue, so I'd suggest trying these. As for my 0.02$ - how large are the images (and how reliable is your internet connection)? Might it be that an image with the same name already exists on the server?

Comment: Yea, i see this links earlier, but its not about my situation. Images, I upload to server is about 1 - 1,5 Mb, internet connection fairly fast. Oddity in file name, when I change it - upload occurs without problem. For all upload images set unique names.

Comment: I want to understand why changing name of file is so influence on uploading.

Comment: The filename shouldn't matter - I suspected the size, as it appears that not entire image is being sent to the server. Can you please humor me and change the size of the image, while keeping the name the same and try uploading it?

Comment: I think so, but changing image size did not help! File name the same.