# Redirecting after sending Email with PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, phpmailer

I have a problem with the redirection after sending an Confirmation Email with `PHPMailer`. The User doesn't get redirected to the `memberIndex.php`.

I've tried with:

```
`$mail->Send();
header("Location:../memberIndex.php");
exit();`
```

Also turning off Debugging with:

```
`$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`
```

And all combinations with `ob_start/flush/clean` etc.

**Note:** When I left the body of the Mail (`$mail->Body`) empty, it sends an email and redirects as it should. Otherwise, it stays on the registration page.
In the Body, I have some HTML-Tags and texts. Could it be, that the body blocks the redirection?

Here is my code where I build the email:

```
require '../../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'host';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'username';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('info@test.com', 'test');
$mail->addAddress('test@test.com');     // Add a recipient


$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../img/text_dark.png', 'cs');
$mail->Subject = 'Hi Customer!';

$body = 'test';

$mail->Body = $body;

$mail->Send();
header("Location:../memberIndex.php");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you are building your email please ?

Comment: _“Could it be, that the body blocks the redirection?”_ - only if you actually output it, so that i becomes part of the response ... // Please go read [ask], and then edit your question, so that it contains some actually helpful details.

Comment: If you have *anything* producing output before you send a Location header, it will fail, and PHP will log an error saying "headers already sent" - so check your log files. PHPMailer does not produce any output unless you ask it to, so either you have some debug output, or you are leaking some other output.

Comment: Consider this before you use 'header' .You should not have printed anything

Comment: I think you need to specify how you build the body of email as that might be the problem here which is not included in your sample code.

Comment: @Kyborek Even if I put 'test' into the body, it doesn't redirect..

Comment: @rey Can you verify (using developer tools) that the server in fact sends you the Location header? Can you verify there is no other output? Can you try using absolute url like this? `header("Location: https://stackoverflow.com/");`

Comment: `$mail->isHTML(true);`... I think it should be `$mail->IsHTML(true);` (uppercase "I") But I don't know if that is the issue... It's the only thing I see.

Comment: Try to wrap it all inside a `try{}` block... Then `catch (phpmailerException $e) { echo $e->errorMessage(); }`

Comment: @Kyborek the only strange thing I can see is the message "Provisional headers are shown" in headers. And that the page calling the header() "stalled". Not familiar with chromes dev Tools but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814960/2159528) about "Provisional headers".

Comment: An idea... Try to add the embedded image after the message body is defined.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Just to make sure the problem isn't coming from PHPMailer... Try `if(!$mail->send()) {  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;  }else{echo "PHPMailer ok."; }`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you! in PHPMailer is everything ok. I guess i have to check my code for whitespaces now.

Answer (score 0):

wrap `$mail->send()` at least (try...catch would be better) in a if block like:

```
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    header("Location:../memberIndex.php");
}
```

to get a clue whats maybe going wrong.
Also have look into [PHP header manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Most important is not to have **any** output before sending a header. No whitspace, no error, no nothing.