# Node js / Angular js - CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

This is my **Angular js** piece code:

```
$http({
                method:'POST',
                withCredential:true,
                url:$scope.config.app_ws+'auth/signup',
                data:{user:$scope.auth}
            }).success(function(status, response){

                console.log(response);
            }).error(function(status, response){
                alert(response+'Bummer :( , an error occured plese retry later. ');
            });
```

This is my **Node.js** piece backend:

```
 var allow_cross_domain= function(req, res, next) {
      res.header('X-Powered-By', 'hey.heyssssssss.org');

      var oneof = false;
      if(req.headers.origin) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        oneof = true;
      }
      if(req.headers['access-control-request-method']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', req.headers['access-control-request-method']);
        oneof = true;
      }
      if(req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        oneof = true;
      }
      if(oneof) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
      }
    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if (oneof && req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
      res.send(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
    }

    app.use(allow_cross_domain);

    app.post('/auth/signup', function (req, res) { res.send('wtff'); });
```

I'm just calling POST localhost:3000/auth/signup from Angular to Node, but i get `**CAUTION : Provisional headers are shown.**` in chrome console.

> Chrome (CAUTION):

[image]

> Firefox (NO RESPONSE for about 30/60 seconds and then the alert() comes up :/ ):

[image]

what this could be?

IF i use GET everything is ok, is just with POST that i get troubles how is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

personaly I use this "reset" method in angular:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
}]);
```

Comment: gosh it's half a day i'm on this bug, thank you it  WORKS!!

Comment: no problem. Spent lots of time looking for the answer myself

Comment: It we be cool if we could know why this happens.

Comment: No request is sent to server when this problem occurs. You may check out this [**SO question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284111/php-jquery-ajax-call-throws-neterr-empty-response). It uses **Jquery AJAX** to communicate with PHP. It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: It is not working for me. Anyone have solution?

Comment: app refers to express, not angular. Or am i missing something?

Comment: check, what are you trying to return in your express route. in my case i was trying to return a large object https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276288/2119981

Answer (score 2):

this was fixed Mar 28, 2014
so it will be ok in next version of crome (v35)

[chromium community](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327581)

Comment: Awesome, but it's still useful for mobile apps coding.

Comment: I am using Chrome 43, still facing this issue.