# AngularJS: POSTing something new with $resource

Tags: angularjs, post, resources

I'm having trouble using $resource to POST something new... It works great for updates & queries, but when I try and create a new 'article', its getting a little confusing.

Basically my POST should be sent to "/articles/". The ID of the article is set through the form on the front end, however when I submit the POST it is sent to "/articles/ARTICLE_ID"(ARTICLE_ID being replaced with whatever I set on the form).

**Here is my article service:**

```
angular.module('testapp.articles')
  .factory("Articles", ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('articles/:articleId', {
        articleId: '@articleId'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

**This is my controller:**

```
$scope.create = function() {
  var article = new Articles({
    articleId: this.articleId
  });
  article.$save(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes off to `/articles/ARTICLE_ID` because that is what you specified while creating the `Article`. You do not need to supply `article_id` as a parameter.

```
$scope.create = function() {
   var article = new Articles();
   article.articleId = this.articleId
   article.$save();
   ...
};
```

With the newer versions of AngularJS, `articleId` will be picked up anyway. Your service could be simplified as follows:

```
angular.module('testapp.articles')
   .factory("Articles", ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('articles/:articleId', null,
            {
                'update': { method: 'PUT' }
            });
}]);
```

[AngularJS $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Although after I changed it, it did stop posting to /articles/:articleId and started posting to /articles/ but my posts were also getting stuck in a "pending" state, with "CAUTION: Provisional Headers are shown" being displayed in the network panel. so I also had to reset the headers using the method found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630534/node-js-angular-js-caution-provisional-headers-are-shown). Its all working now!