# how to prevent "Provisional headers are shown" in angularjs ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call in angularjs application. but randomly i am getting this caution says "Provisional headers are shown" and whenever this caution comes in debugger console I am getting very slow response from server (about 30 to 45 sec). and its happening around 6 times in 10 times trial period.

this is my angularjs piece of code:-

```
var request = $http({
                  method:"post",
                  url:"/getdata.php",
                  data:filterpara,                              
                  headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}                       
            }); 

        request.success(function(data){ 

                    console.log(data);

        });
```

This type of piece of code I am using number of times in different controllers. but randomly same issue is coming in different controllers as well. i am unable to figure out why this is happening?

I have also tried the solutions which is already provided by these links (but no luck) :-

[Node js / Angular js - CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630534/node-js-angular-js-caution-provisional-headers-are-shown) (this kind of problem I am facing)

["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

Comment: I have the same exact issue and neither of the other answers helped me, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Sometimes it's the AdBlock interfering, try disabling it if you have ome

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's the AdBlock interfering, try disabling it if you have one and retry.

Comment: In my case, my api was trying to return a huge JSON object. When I have tried to send a small object, it was working fine. Finally, I have changed my implementation to return a buffer instead of a JSON.