# JS and CSS Bundles not working in elastic beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my mvc 4.0 .net application working fine locally, but after I deploy it to Amazon's elastic beanstalk, the js and css bundles are not working.  The response comes back blank.  Anyone have this issue?

EDIT:
According to this:
["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

The server never responds, leading me to believe that bundles are not supported by elastic beanstalk?

EDIT:

Also, could it be that I moved the code from 4.5 to 4.0?

Comment: Gave up on this, switched to azure.

Answer (score 0):

AWS looks to support both 4.0 and 4.5. Can you get the logs from the beanstalk dashboard?