# Google Analytics's _trackEvent is not working - Showing CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-chrome-devtools, google-analytics-api

I've written this below line in `onclick` of `<a/>`

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', 'OS', 'Server']);
```

But I'm getting this error in Network tab of Google Chrome, and its not registering event in Google Analytics.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en
to debug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an ad-blocker **and** dc.js is being served from the "doubleclick" domain, your request could be getting blocked.

Comment: This response does not answer the question. The original post did not mention use of ad-blockers, nor is it relevant to the error received.

Comment: @TylerEich dc.js doesn't get blocked by most (all?) adBlockers by default. But this might be the right answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger

Comment: @Eduardo Good point. I submitted an edit to make the original statement (which I misunderstood) clearer.