# provisional header are shown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the below code first time the code is working when i give print next time print is not working and then when i give refresh the browser is loading long time .

this is php code

```
  <p><img src="images/logo_print.png" width="635" height="143" alt="" /></p>
  <h3>Test title</h3>
  <h4><strong>Authors : Author name</p>
  <h4><strong>Author Address : </strong></h4><p>Author Address</p>
  <h4><strong>Abstract : </strong></h4><p style="text-align:justify;"> abstract</p>
  <h4><strong>Keywords : </strong></h4><p>Keyword</p>
  <div class="cls" style="border-top:1px solid #656565; margin:10px 0px;"></div>
```

**javascript code is**

```
 enter code here

  function PrintParts(arrElementNames){

 var objWindow=window.open("about:blank", "print", "left=0, top=0, width=800,    height=430, toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes");
 var strHtml="<html><link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
 strHtml += "<head>";
 strHtml += "</head>";
 strHtml += "<body><table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% bgcolor=#FFFFFF>";
 strHtml += "<tr><td height=10>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";
 strHtml += "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% bgcolor=#ffffff><tr><td>"

 for (var i=0; i<arrElementNames.length; i++){
  var element=document.getElementById(arrElementNames[i]);
  strHtml += element.innerHTML; 
  }

 strHtml +="</td></tr> ";
 strHtml +="</table>";
 strHtml += "</body>";
 strHtml += "</html>";
 objWindow.document.write(strHtml);
 objWindow.document.close();
 objWindow.print();
 objWindow.close();
  }
```

the error is shown as:

**CAUTION : Provisional headers are shown.**

how can i solve this problem in this coding. i am really wast of my time but i can't solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Caution provisional headers are shown in chrome debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

Comment: How can i solve this problem in this coding please any one help me by Ashok kumar

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975943/php-serve-mp4-chrome-provisional-headers-are-shown-request-is-not-finished-ye , did u solve it by any chance?