# Amazon S3 Error Firewall Provisional headers are shown

Tags: php, video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, firewall

I am having a issue regarding Amazon S3 urls giving the error

> Provisional headers are shown

I only seem to get this error when i am connected to the wifi over certain networks my main problem is when i am in starbucks on their WIFI i get the error but on any other WIFI i dont get the error and the video will play fine.

I am using the latest Amazon PHP SDK to provide signed urls like below.

```
$url = $client->getObjectUrl('videos', 'movie.mp4', '+59 minutes', array(
                            'ResponseContentType' => 'video/mp4'
                        ));
```

This will generate me a signed url like this.

> https://video.s3.amazonaws.com/movie.mp4?response-content-type=video%2Fmp4&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJHLH6A2TDNLM37YQ&Expires=1409164722&Signature=melsHcsVaXRONs72dhNqM407Cnc%3D

Below is the working version which has a content range bytes

```
    Accept-Ranges:bytes
    Content-Length:141956
    Content-Range:bytes 9223221-9365176/9365177
    Content-Type:video/mp4
    Date:Wed, 27 Aug 2014 17:39:44 GMT
    ETag:"3fde140b11d9ebb5ef8480aa859c78de"
    Last-Modified:Mon, 29 Jul 2013 10:56:00 GMT
    Server:AmazonS3
    x-amz-id-2:1+rCBJveiYu1d+fWgrvioqijD7kF3fkMNVnSi3Le8LVERwxAtRKRSSj7z7Ma01vy
    x-amz-request-id:8D1E676B0D61E8FD
```

But when i am on starbucks WIFI i get the error.

Provisional headers are shown

But no bytes range 0-

I know this is vague question and someone will probably instantly down vote it but it is a genuine issue i am experiencing and i really need to get it resolved.

It means anyone watching videos on my website wont be able to view them over certain WIFI connections normally public ones all i can think is it maybe a firewall error.

Any help please or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess it that there is no error, and StarBucks has just decided to block that traffic for whatever reason their firewall deemed fit.

Provisional headers returned seems to indicate that a request was blocked. More info about that can be found here. ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

Comment: Thanks drummin this is probably correct as i cannot find anymore info on this issue