# Sencha touch app for android ajax request getting empty response with request headers "Causion : Provisional headers are shown"

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, cordova

I'm using sencha touch with cordova to create mobile app for android. In mobile browser its working fine. when i create android apk, first ajax request getting proper response with request header showing "Causion : Provisional headers are shown". but second ajax request didn't getting any reponse. showing empty response.

i searched last full week but still i didn't get any correct answer. From my search i got few points, these thinks only affect ajax request with server.

1) add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *" in headers or htaccess.

colud you any one tell what is the core point. any thing i missed ?

- This issue regarding about chrome debugging ?
- Application frameworks issue like Zend framework / Sencha Touch / Cordova app for android ?
- need to add headers in ajax request or need to change ajax request to jonp ?
- need to add headers in php server or .htaccess file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

Comment: wich version of cordova are you using?

Comment: cordova 4.1.2 and android 3.7.1

Comment: @Sumurai8 could you explain how to solve this issues ?

Comment: Your question is vague. If provisional headers are shown for the request header, the client did not send a request for some reason. Why this is we don't know. Try testing it in incognito mode with ALL extensions turned off. Hell, even a firewall could be the problem here, resetting the connection before it is even made.

Comment: thanks @Sumurai8. i will check and let you know. if any improvement.