# How does cookie work with HTTP?

Tags: http, cookies

I just recently used network inspector for youtube requests while logged in as some user.

I notice that for requests like

https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U

The request looks like[image]

So how does youtube even tell what the current user is? The request header is pretty much empty. So it doesn't have any kind of session token or other stuff.

My guess is that it somehow reads my browser cookies.

So does that mean, all my browser cookies related to this site is sent together with the HTTP request each time a request is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Provisional headers are shown` message is shown in `Request Headers` because the headers displayed in DevTool are not the actual headers sent to the server. This may be caused by several reasons: AdBlock, Cache is used, request pending etc. You can check ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger) for some previous discussion.

**So how does youtube even tell what the current user is? The request header is pretty much empty.**

It's not empty, the headers are just not displayed in DevTool.

**So does that mean, all my browser cookies related to this site is sent together with the HTTP request each time a request is made?**

Not exactly. It depends on the cookie's `domain` and `path`. If the cookie's `domain` match the HTTP request's host, and its `path` match the HTTP request's URL path, the cookie will be sent to server. Otherwise, it will be ignored in the HTTP request.

For example, there are 3 cookies:

- Cookie A, whose `domain` is `example.com`, `path` is `/`.
- Cookie B, whose `domain` is `test.example.com`, `path` is `/`.
- Cookie C, whose `domain` is `example.com`, `path` is `/list`.

When a request is sent to `http://example.com/news`, only Cookie A is sent to server, Cookie B and C will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Perfect!