# Angular 4 get call stuck browser and application

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 application I have a problem with a standard http get, and in Chrome if I see the header of this call I see: `Provisional headers are shown` afer that call chrome remains stucked, I need to kill it to make it works again.

If I try to debug I see that the map operator in my service is not executed, and also the subscribe in the component is not executed.
This Get make the call with the correct link, and it is not a backend problem,

so why my application/chrome result stucked and I can't see any errors?

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.loadNotes(10);
  }



  loadNotes(items: number) {
    this.noteService.getNotes2(this.link, items, this.currentPage)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('subscribe');
        this.ticketBundleNoteList = response._embedded.notes as Note[]; 
      },
      error => {console.log('error')})
}
```

**noteService**

```
 getNotes2(url: string, items, page) {

    let params = new HttpParams().set('size', items);
    params = params.set('page', page);
    console.log('SERVICE NOTE')
      return this.http.get('http://....../api/v1/depositReceipts/search/getNotes?id=1')
        .map((response) => <any>response)
    }
```

Comment: "*I see that the map operator in my service is not executed*". There is no `.map` in the provided code ..?

Comment: updated, I forgot it when copied the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger check this, maybe AdBlock is the cause

Comment: @DanilGudz no, nothing change

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not somewhere else? Since browser freezes, seems to me it could be something else like an infinite loop or something. Your code works fine without this pieces of code?

Comment: @AJT_82 good point, this component is included in other component and load the notes `<app-note-sidebar-cmp
[link]="searchNotes"> </app-note-sidebar-cmp> `

Comment: in addition to above point, what's going on in your network tab, are there multiple calls?