# Provisional headers are shown

Tags: node.js, extjs5

I am using Extjs in web and node.js in the api side. I called the api defined, from the web. I passed params and required data as request, but its showing the below error and request is unsuccessful.

[image]

Here is the api call code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/update-fund",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            params: {
                userId: userDocGlobal.id
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            jsonData: {
                fundId: PECalculator.selectedFund,
                fundDate: getAiqDateFromPicker(Ext.getCmp("currentCalculationDateFundLevel")),
                fundData: fund,
                ownerId: userDocGlobal.companyid,
                lpId: userDocGlobal.companyid,
                role: userDocGlobal.role,
                userId: userDocGlobal.id,
                companyid: userDocGlobal.companyid
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(response);
                }
                if(userRole === "FREE"){
                    moduleObj.setFundNameAndCalcDateForFreeUser();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                if (errorCallback) {
                    errorCallback();
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Is there any `token` based authentication >

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger

Comment: This answer has worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848952/2705070