# How to send x-csrf-token in a GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to send the x-csrf-token along with the URL in a GET request. I am using request-promise nodejs package for this purpose, but I don't know how to do.

I need to do something like this:

```
return rp({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://alabbo.to/joiner?fid=5ba900635da0a&page=check",
    CSRF: "Y5KLHznEcspsqDHgmy63UHvKZT8s48EuQ1bfv34n"
})
    .then(function (html) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF is sent inside headers with key name `X-CSRF-Token` as shown below

```
return rp({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://alabbo.to/joiner?fid=5ba900635da0a&page=check", 
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token': "Y5KLHznEcspsqDHgmy63UHvKZT8s48EuQ1bfv34n"
    }
}).then(function (html) {
})
```

Comment: Yes indeed it makes sense. But I actually fixed my issue thanks to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger I did not even need a token, it was simply not working because my adblock blocked the request...

Answer (score 0):

Atishay is right, X-CSRF-Token is a header.

Otherway, is you use Node v8, you can use async / await instead of `.then`.

`const response = await rp({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://alabbo.to/joiner?fid=5ba900635da0a&page=check", 
    headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token': "Y5KLHznEcspsqDHgmy63UHvKZT8s48EuQ1bfv34n"
    }
})`