# "Provisional headers are shown" warning in Chrome web-console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, request-headers

When I log in (and restart Chrome app) with my Google account into the Chrome browser I start to get the "Provisional headers are shown" warning in the web-inspector (`Network` tab, `XHR` section).
 After logout this warning doesn't disappear until I manually remove Chrome folder in `~/Library/Application Support/Google`.

I don't see all headers for request next to the warning label and don't see `Set-Cookie` header in response and `Cookie` header in request.

- Requests are sent, and they have response body, etc.
- All Chrome addons are turned off.
- No installed Chrome themes.
- Account settings reset to default.
- Warning is reproducible in incognito tab.
- Latest Mac OS, latest Chrome version.

Comment: "Provisional headers are shown" is a normal thing to see until a request completes. Are you saying that _all_ network requests, even those that are successful, are missing details in your network inspector?

Comment: I suspect you'll just need to reinstall Google Chrome. It's doubtful this forum can resolve a problem with your browser setup.

Comment: "all network requests, even those that are successful" - exactly. Requests are finished, I can see status, response body, etc, but this warning is still there. That's the point.

Comment: "I suspect you'll just need to reinstall Google Chrome" - I've done it, nothing changed.

Comment: This answer has worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848952/2705070