# Chrome does not show request cookies when "Provisional Headers are shown"

Tags: google-chrome

When I set a breakpoint in my server application and make a request to the paused endpoint with Chrome, cookies are not shown in the request while the debugger is sitting on it. I spent a moment debugging why the client wasn't sending cookies until I realized what was going on - cookies exist but are not displayed. Why does this happen?

Yes I know about ["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger), but this doesn't answer why some headers are shown and others aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=294891:

> Headers displayed for pending requests are provisional. They represent
>   what request was sent from Blink to Chromium.
>
> We do not update headers until server responds to avoid additional
>   notification used only by DevTools.
>
> To watch real network activity you can use chrome://net-internals