# Chrome show Provisional headers are shown without cookies in request

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, cross-domain

There are so many problems about this
For example

["CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" in Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger)

[Chrome does not show request cookies when "Provisional Headers are shown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753181/chrome-does-not-show-request-cookies-when-provisional-headers-are-shown)

I want to inpect cookies from CORS requests

[image]

[image]

You can see, response has status code 200.

But I can't see cookies

someone tell me to disable `chrome://flags/#site-isolation-trial-opt-out`

I done it, but when chrome restart, it show

[image]

Same url works in Firefox, I can see cookies in request
[image]

At
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation#TOC-Known-Issues

said:

> n Chrome's DevTools, cookies and other request headers are not shown in the network panel for cross-site subresource requests. 
>   There are also issues with the DOM storage view, security panel, performance panel, and with scrolling over cross-site iframes in mobile device emulation mode, 
>   **all of which are fixed in Chrome 68.**

But My chrome still have this problem.

Could you give me a solution?

Env:

Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Windows 10 pro 1809/OSBuild: 17763.379

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer seems to be you need to set

```
Enable network service
```

option to *disabled*.

Comment: I tried but don't works, your answer included by @vvsage

Comment: The fact is that you said " I have set [..] `network service` to _enabled_" . That's wrong, you would need to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

two steps:

1.go to chrome://flags/

2.Disable site isolation,
  Enable network service,
  Runs network service in-process

make sure all those three options are set to Disabled

Don't ask me why. It works for me @Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169

Comment: after disable `site isolation`, chrome show `you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-site-isolation-trials. Stability and security will suffer`, I have set `isolation` to `disabled`, `network service` to `enabled`, but still have above problem..

Comment: enable `site isolation` will fix the problem. but you won't be able to inspect cookie anymore.