# Puppeteer browser referer list

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, referer

I would like to load random list of `referers` from my default location path , for example: `'referers.txt'` instead of adding direct "facebook url as referer.

My code:

```js
browser = await puppeteer.getBrowserInstance(port);
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setDefaultTimeout(PAGE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * 1000);
page.on('error', handlePageCrash(page));
page.on('pageerror', handlePageCrash(page));
page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ referer: 'https://www.facebook.com/' });
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a txt you should choose [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) to store your list of referer values in an array.

**referers.json**

```json
["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com", "https://www.instagram.com"]
```

Then you will be able to pick a random element form the array by: `array[randomIndex]`. To generate a random number for the length of your array you have multiple possibilities, `Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)` only one of them.

**referers.js**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const referers = require('./referers.json')

async function fn() {
  const randomReferer = referers[Math.floor(Math.random() * referers.length)]
  console.log(referers)
  console.log(randomReferer)
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, devtools: true })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ referer: randomReferer })

  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/')
}
fn()
```

**output example:**

```
[
  'https://www.google.com',
  'https://www.facebook.com',
  'https://www.instagram.com'
]
https://www.facebook.com
```

Comment: Can I do the same way for Useragents?

Comment: sure, why not? actually the solution I gave is rather Node/JavaScript answer to your problem. You can randomize anything like this, then re-use the strings as values for puppeteer methods.

Comment: with random useragents I get error I will create new question if you want to check later thx

Comment: Ok I made new question here pls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973252/puppeteer-browser-useragent-list

Comment: It shows a warning Provisional headers warning in the network tab

Comment: @SkyRar it may answers your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger. if those don't help, it would be useful to know which version of puppeteer with which chromium you use it