# Puppeteer Random user-agent args

Tags: random, puppeteer, user-agent

Recently I asked this random useragents from .json file but the thing is that after I added "capture screen" of puppeteer it keeps showing headless chrome, so I copied the previous topic answer into wrong place.

**Now the real useragent js page came from this page:**

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: false,
args: ['--headless', '--disable-infobars', '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36', '--no-sandbox', `--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:${port}`] : ['--no-sandbox'],
```

});

So how do I create rnadom list inside the arguments?
My previous help which doesnt worked for me as the random useragents code was not in correct place is here: [Puppeteer browser useragent list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63973252/puppeteer-browser-useragent-list/63976320)

But adding that code inside this wont work.

So after `--user-agent=` I want to add "`random`" function but how?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `user-agents` module.
You should install `npm install user-agents`

```
const UserAgent = require("user-agents");
const userAgent = new UserAgent({
   deviceCategory: "desktop",
   platform: "Linux x86_64",
 });
```

Then in the head `"--user-agent=" + userAgent + "",`

Comment: You don't need the params.

Comment: Though thank you so much for the answer I was looking for a while.