# axios instance not working as expected in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a component called Login.js There I import Axios libray normal way and it works like this.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const data = await axios.post('/user/login/', {
        email: e.email,
        password: e.password,
      });
```

[image]

Getting 404 is fine because I didn't set any base URL for the Axios. Please note all the requests, response headers here.

Then I try to created Axios instance inside a lib folder and import it like this

/src/lib/axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseUrl,
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

I import this instance instead of normal Axios import.

```
import axios from 'libs/axios';
```

Now I see the request like this a lot of properties missing in the request and this isn't working
[image]

How do I fix this?

Any help thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `.env` file look like? You said your file is `src/lib/axios.js` so why are you importing `libs/axios`?

Comment: @Phil because it is in the same folder probably.

Comment: @gguney `libs` is not `lib`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger . Please, don't spam with irrelevant tags